# Why does SpaceX have a launch window for a pad abort test?

Tags: launch, spacex, spacecraft-development, dragon, testing

SpaceX has [announced](http://www.floridatoday.com/story/tech/science/space/spacex/2015/04/21/spacex-targets-may-dragon-pad-abort-test/26131859/?from=global&sessionKey=&autologin=) a pad abort test for the Dragon crew capsule on May 5th. They have a 4 hour launch window for the test.

There is no destination, so why would there be a launch window in this case?

Answer (score 28):

There are many different constraints that putting a time window around a launch attempt (even a pad abort) can help manage. Orbital constraints, facilities availability and many more.

In the case of a Pad Abort, consider the flight path. Ignite the Super Dracos, get high enough for the parachutes to be effective, and land in the ocean just off the coast.

That means a Notice to Mariners that they need to stay out of an exclusion area. Thus a launch window puts boundaries on the maritime exclusion zone.

Comment: Also, any rocket operation that involves the rocket (or any part of it) flying will need a [TFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Aviation_Regulations#Temporary_flight_restrictions) to tell airplanes to stay out of the area.

Answer (score 6):

There are all kinds of time constraints on a range.  The obvious ones involve rendezvousing with another vehicle on orbit, but there are other, more mundane ones.  For example, work shifts and sunlight hours.

Comment: Question is about Pad Abort, not any orbital insertion...